# Weblogic,EJB, $Proxy99 class cast exception

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-6, weblogic11g

Following are the modules in my project,
 **1. EJB module (version 3):** We prepare ejb jar of this module and deploy on Weblogic11g server. It deals with database operation. It has @local, @Remote interface and @stateless classes implementing @local,@Remote interfaces.
 **2. Web Application :** This web application takes inputs (user uploads file) from users, validates file and inserts data into database. It uses RMI.

**Problem:** On production (weblogic 11g server ) sometimes we observe exception saying $Proxy99 cannot be cast to "Remote interface name"  (for different different classes) e.g com.xyz.fileProcessSetting.FileProcessSttgFacadeRemote.
But after some time when we again upload file, it gets uploaded successfully without any error.
Now, I do not understand how come these remote objects becomes temporarily unavailable? Never faced this issue on development/UAT environment. Also no idea how to reproduce and fix it.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
@Remote
public interface FileProcessSttgFacadeRemote {
//methods
}

@Local
public interface FileProcessSttgFacadeLocal {
//methods
}

@Stateless
public class FileProcessSttgFacade implements FileProcessSttgFacadeLocal, FileProcessSttgFacadeRemote {
//methods
}
```

in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

```
<weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>FileProcessSttgFacade</ejb-name>
    <stateless-session-descriptor>
        <business-interface-jndi-name-map>
            <business-remote>com.xyz.fileProcessSetting.FileProcessSttgFacadeRemote</business-remote>
            <jndi-name>FileProcessSttgFacade</jndi-name>
        </business-interface-jndi-name-map>
    </stateless-session-descriptor>
</weblogic-enterprise-bean>
```

In web application also in ejb module whenever we want to call methods we use following lookup method to get remote object:

```
public class someclass extends EjbLocator {
    public void someMethod(){

        FileProcessSttgFacadeRemote fpfr = (FileProcessSttgFacadeRemote) getService("FileProcessSttgFacade");
        //other code
    }
}
```

Following is the class used for JNDI lookup:

```
public class EjbLocator {

    public Object getService(final String jndiName) throws Exception {
        try {
            obj = getDefaultContext().lookup(jndiName);
        } catch (final Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    protected Context getDefaultContext() {
        try {
            final Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"weblogic");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://<ip>:<port>");
            defaultContext = new InitialContext(env);
            return defaultContext;
        } catch (final NamingException nExp) {
            nExp.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example how you retrieve reference to EJB?

Comment: @slwk: I have added few code snippets

Comment: Since you have your `FileProcessSttgFacade` implementing both `@Local` and `@Remote` interfaces, but when you're looking them up you're not specifying none of them, it may be possible that sometimes you're getting the right interface (Remote) or sometimes the wrong one (Local). Try seeing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2580930/1346996) answer in order to narrow your problem. And don't forget that your `@Local` implementation is always available across your application (same JVM) whereas the `@Remote` may not be.